# Почему значение репутации в списке отличается от оного на графике в течении какого-то времени?

Tags: дефект, репутация, профиль-участника

Причина явно не в кеше, ведь раз в списке отображается нормально, значит эти данные уже есть. Но списке отображает +30 репы:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А на графике +20:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А сейчас? .....

Comment: @АндрейNOP сейчас то уже норм.

Comment: Значит дело в кэше